# BNN predictive distribution $p(y(x)|D) = \int p(y(x)|w)p(w|D) dw$, what is $p(y(x)|w)$?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

When we use approximation methods to try to approximate the predictive distribution, I am slightly troubled by $p(y(x)|D) = \int p(y(x)|w)p(w|D) dw$. Since $y(x) = f(w, x)$ (as $y(x)$ is the neural network model) and $x$ is a fixed input - so surely $p(y(x)|w)$ is deterministic and therefore a point distribution?

More generally can someone explain what $p(y(x)|w)$ actually is in the context of bayesian neural networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $x$ is a fixed input, but it isn't clear to me that $p(y(x)|w)$
should be described as either a random/deterministic quantity, or a point distribution. It is simply a conditional probability (usually a density) function.

In a simpler setting, consider $y|w\sim N(w,1)$, then $p(y|w)$ is simply the distribution of a normal centered at $w$. With this example in mind, $p(y(x)|w)$ is just the conditional probability function of $y(x)$ conditioned on the weights. These functions better be deterministic as a function of its arguments.

To better understand why this appears, when we compute the posterior predictive, we are essentially weighting the probability of observing $y(x)$ under $w$, and integrating over all possible values of $w$. $w$ is distributed according to the posterior you fitted in your model, $p(w|D)$.

Comment: Ah, I see, in the context of bayesian neural networks - I was thinking that y would be a deterministic output (sort of treating it as a neural network) if you specify the weights $w$ and input $x$. I have seen mentioned that you can view BNNs as an "infinite ensemble of NNs" since we express the predictive posterior as $E_{p(w|D)}[p(\hat{y}|x,w)]$. I would think that whats inside the expectation is deterministic under this interpretation of BNNs

Comment: Further reading in Tibshiranis Elements of Statistical Learning: https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/NoHesitations/BookAdvanced.pdf says to treat them as class probabilities as in a classification problem. So notationally do we use a probabilistic notation for the neural network? Because I understand fully if $y$ had stochastic dependence on $w$ the idea. But if $y = f(w)$ as is the case in a standard neural network - I would think the likelihood is trivial?

Comment: @Governor $p(y|x,w)$ is still random. It depends on the distribution of $w|D\sim p(w|D)$. So the thing inside your expectation is not deterministic. I don't follow what you mean by the likelihood would be trivial.